# When I upgraded to AGP7+, the packaging kept getting this error: MergeJavaResWorkAction ZipException

Tags: android

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeCommonReleaseJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
```

The configuration I use is：

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
}
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

I hope it's packed correctly